# Getting formatted output of ILogger.Log for other destination

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog, structured-logging

The widely-recommended pattern is to always allow ILogger to format its messages rather than passing it a pre-formatted string. [CA2254](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2254) even chastises you if you don't. In a UI application, there are often cases where we want to log a message to the UI as well as the log. An error dialog would be simple (ugly) example. In that case, it would be tempting to do something like:

```c#
string message = $"Exception while doing a thing. Code={ex.Code}, {ex.Message}";
_logger.LogError(message);
Dialog.Open(Icon.Error, message);
```

That breaks the pattern. Other than constant repetition/duplication of code, is there a good terse way to define the message in a logger-friendly way and get immediate access to the formatted result for use **in the same context as the original `Log` invocation**? To be clear, I'm not talking about monitoring the stream of messages elsewhere and funneling them all to a list on the UI. For example, is there a way to get to code like this, maintaining the normal efficiencies of loggers?

```c#
LogMessage message = new(LogLevel.Error, "Exception while doing a thing. Code={ex.Code}, {ex.Message}", ex.Code, ex.Message);
_logger.Log(message);
Dialog.Open(Icon.Error, message.ToString());
```

Comment: To my knowledge, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and ILogger doesn't provide a public way of invoking the internal formatting code. I've seen people copy and paste the internal implementation of this from the source on GitHub, but it's not something I would recommend. I would never output exception details like the exception message to the user. This belongs in the log for a developer to look at.

Comment: This is just an accessible example. Of course not every log message is an exception. Many are informational messages that are just as interesting to the user as they are to the person reading the log. I'm just looking for an elegant way to avoid three ugly options:
1. Formatting twice.
2. Suppressing compiler warnings.
3. Tricking the compiler by using the whole message as a log argument.